# Multiple background images with different heights

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image

I am trying to have a Bootstrap Jumbotron that contains 2 background images.  The general idea is as illustrated in the attached image.  At the bottom layer is a full width photo (indicated in gray) and on top of it is a transparent PNG (indicated in yellow).  The height of the Jumbotron is set at 350px, which is for the full-width photo.  Having said that, I would like to top layer to go beyond 350px so it is overlapping the text in the div below the Jumbotron.  How would you suggest me to achieve this?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE5GQ.jpg)

I have some HTML markup as follows:

```
<body>
<section class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Tag line in a Bootstrap Jumbotron</h1>
</section>

<section>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...</p>
</section>
</body>
```

I have the following CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
     background-image: url("top.png"), url("bottom.jpg");
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: scroll;
     background-position: 50% 0%;
     height: 350px;
}
```

With these codes, I am able to stack the 2 background images properly so that the transparent top layer is sitting nicely on top of the bottom layer.  However, I do not know how I can make the top layer go beyond the 350px such that it can overlap the text below.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

*** UPDATE ***
So I attempted in answering my own question.  I made some progress but the solution does not seem complete.  Here's what I did...

I added an additional div to only hold the top transparent PNG layer and use negative margin to push it up to cover the jumbotron.  But when I did that, the tagline in the jumbotron can no longer be highlighted/selected.  It appears as if the top transparent PNG layer is covering it up.  I tried playing with z-index but that didn't help.  Here's my updated HTML:

```
<body>
<section class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Tag line in a Bootstrap Jumbotron</h1>
</section>

<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="png-layer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content row">
        <div>
           <h2>Title</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
```

Updated CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
     background-image: url("bottom.jpg");
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: scroll;
     background-position: 50% 0%;
     height: 350px;
}
.png-layer {
     background-image: url("top.png");
     height: 500px;
     margin-top: -350px;
}
.content {
     margin-top: -200px;
}
```

Any ideas on how to fine-tune to solution to make it to perfection?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can't technically make a background image exceed the thing it's a background on, but using a pseudo-element, you might be able to fake it: https://www.exratione.com/2011/09/how-to-overflow-a-background-image-using-css3/

Comment: Hmm...would there be other options? Like let's say we throw away the idea of having 2 background images for the jumbotron?  Maybe I was on the wrong track in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is (in my opinion and as you correctly pointed out in the update to your question) to create a `div` that exclusively holds the .png you want to overlay on top of the Jumbotron and the text. **The CSS of this element should include:**

- `z-index:xxxx;` where `xxxx` is whatever value allows your div to be shown on top of the image you intent to use as a background (i.e. higher than its containing `div`) but lower than the text you want it to appear under. Also remember that `z-index` works only on elements for which you have defined the `position` attribute.
- `pointer-events: none;` so that you can still select the text below it.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, @Fausto NA! The `pointer-events: none;` was what made it to work!

Comment: You're welcome. Consider upvoting the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: I wanted to but I am too new here and don't have enough reputation scores to vote...  =(  perhaps you can consider upvoting my question to boost my reputation.  =p

Comment: Oh. Here's my help. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks, man! I am just a few scores away from being able to vote! Cheers!